# Create JQuery popover with varying content for all elements with same name

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have the content of a JQuery popover be dependent on the value of the element. The popover is created, but there is no content. This is what I'm trying (and it isn't producing anything for the content)
JQuery:

```
 $("[name=teacher]").popover({
    title: 'Teacher',
    content: $(this).attr('value'),
    trigger: "hover"
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div name="teacher" value="foo1">Bar1</div>
<div name="teacher" value="foo2">Bar2</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, value and name is not a valid attribute for the div element. You should use the data attributes and classnames instead:

```
<div class="teacher" data-value="foo1">Bar1</div>
```

You can access the data attribute like this:

```
$(this).data('value');
```

About the popover stuff. $(this) is for the popover, not for the current element that you are clicking on, so thats why the content is empty. You need to manually trigger the hover function first and then show the popover:

```
$(".teacher").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover({
        content: $(this).data('value')
    }).popover('show');
}, function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

​
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LjmrG/

Comment: See my updated answer, now it works with multiple elements, and you can see a jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

Try using val() function... something like this...

```
$(this).val();
```

might work...